# Django: all identical UUIDs after migration

Tags: python, django, database-migration

I have a mixin to add an UUID to any model:

```
class UUIDable(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(db_index=True,
                     default=uuid.uuid4,
                     editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I have an existing database with `Article` objects inside.
I just added an uuid field to the `Article` class using the mixin above.
After running the migration, all my articles now have the **SAME** UUID.
I expected all the objects to have a different UUID.

Why?

Here is the automatically created migration file:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('products', '0009_auto_20171218_1630'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='article',
            name='uuid',
            field=models.UUIDField(db_index=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False),
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your migration is adding a singular value, and you'll need to alter it during your migration. See this link: ["Migrations that add unique fields"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/)

Try altering the field in the migration:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import uuid

def create_uuid(apps, schema_editor):
    Article = apps.get_model('products', 'Article')
    for device in Article.objects.all():
        device.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        device.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('products', '0009_auto_20171218_1630'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='article',
            name='uuid',
            field=models.UUIDField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(create_uuid),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='article',
            name='uuid',
            field=models.UUIDField(unique=True)
        )
    ]
```